# Git: How do I keep update with a specific branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

**Question 1** What if I have not yet created any git repo locally, and I need to first time sync with a specific branch.

**Question 2** What if I my local folder is git  is currently in sync with Master, and I want to completely sync with another branch ?

Comment: I'm sure someone will answer your questions directly, but I would strongly recommend reading Chapter 2 of the Git Book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "I have nothing locally"?
2. What do you mean by "discard all those in master"? Do you mean undo any local changes since the last commit?

Comment: Yep, question is unclear, please update.

Comment: @yuan to say "I want to sync with another branch" is actually a bit too vague as well. Do you want to merge the changes in the other branch into master? Or rather, do you want to "check out" that other branch so that you can work on it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you don't have a local repo, then you have nothing. You first have to clone the remote repository using `git clone <remote_repo_url>`.
2. If you want to start developing on a different branch, then if the name of that branch is `branch_name`, execute the command `git checkout branch_name`. Note that this assumes the branch exists on your local repository. If it only exists on the remote repository, run the command `git fetch --all` to pull all remote branches onto your local branch.

Comment: By the way, no offense intended, but if you're asking a question like, "How do I work on a branch if I don't have a repository", then it indicates that you have a complete lack of understanding of even the most fundamental aspects of git. You should read the docs: http://git-scm.com/doc . If you don't, you'll be confused at every turn; and coming to SO for help on all the git things you don't understand is going to be a much slower process for you than learning the system the proper way: by reading the docs.

Comment: As an additional note on my above comment -- learning git (and learning it well) is undoubtedly one of the best time commitments you will ever make as a programmer. It's an incredibly powerful and elegant tool, and learning it is well worth your time! Good luck, and good choice using git :-)